# SQL Constraint on more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have a table `PROPERTY_RUNTIME` having the columns of `PROPERTY_NAME` AND `PROPERTY_VALUE`

[table PROPERTY_RUNTIME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDm9E.png)

I am adding a constraint to make the values of `CNT_DISP_PREP1` and `CNT_DISP_PREP2` not equal to 0 at the same time:

```
ALTER TABLE KLASSX.PROPERTY_RUNTIME 

ADD (
  CONSTRAINT CK_BOTH_LINE_CLOSE

CHECK (
  (

  CASE

    WHEN 
    (
    ((PROPERTY_NAME = 'CNT_DISP_PREP1') AND (PROPERTY_VALUE = '1')) 
    OR 
    ((PROPERTY_NAME = 'CNT_DISP_PREP2') AND (PROPERTY_VALUE = '1'))
    )
  THEN 1

  ELSE 0

END
  ) = 1
  )

DISABLE NOVALIDATE);
```

However, when I activate the constraint, and enter four combinations: 1/1, 1/0, 0/1, 0/0, all the four combinations violate the constraint, rather than that only 0/0 violates.

So I wonder if I have any logical mistake in the constraint?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no formal error in the constraint itself - but it does not reflect the logic you wanted to implement. The constraint applies to just one row at a time - it checks the values in PROPERTY_NAME and PROPERTY_VALUE and it applies the conditions **on the same values** (always a single row, in isolation, at a time). Constraints on more than one row at the same time are exceptionally difficult to implement in current SQL (Oracle or any other vendor).

Comment: Also: Someone made some very sensible edits to your post. You then over-edited and made a mess again. Not cool!

Comment: You need to create the TRIGGER for such type of multi-row checks

Comment: Thank you @mathguy for your answer, so would it be easier to user TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE?

Comment: BEFORE INSERT AND UPDATE trigger would be helpful here

Comment: Thank you @Tejash for your answer, I will try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a unique index to enforce that rule across multiples rows as follows:

```
FSITJA@db01> create table property_runtime (property_name varchar2(30), property_value varchar2(1));

Table created.

FSITJA@db01> create unique index ck_both_line_close on property_runtime (
  2    case when property_name in ('CNT_DISP_PREP1', 'CNT_DISP_PREP2') and property_value = '0'
  3         then 1 end)
  4    ;

Index created.

FSITJA@db01> insert into property_runtime values ('CNT_DISP_PREP1', '1');

1 row created.

FSITJA@db01> insert into property_runtime values ('CNT_DISP_PREP2', '1');

1 row created.

FSITJA@db01> insert into property_runtime values ('CNT_DISP_PREP1', '0');

1 row created.

FSITJA@db01 2019-10-18 11:46:08> insert into property_runtime values ('CNT_DISP_PREP2', '0');
insert into property_runtime values ('CNT_DISP_PREP2', '0')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (FSITJA.CK_BOTH_LINE_CLOSE) violated

FSITJA@db01> insert into property_runtime values ('CNT_DISP_PREP1', '0');
insert into property_runtime values ('CNT_DISP_PREP1', '0')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (FSITJA.CK_BOTH_LINE_CLOSE) violated
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I solved the issue with unique index